# Active model serializer 0.9.4 stack too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Hi the serailizer in my application looks like this

```
class ProgressSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_one :race
end

class RaceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id
  has_many :progresses 
end
```

The has_one and has_many together gives me error stack level too deep.
Things I tried.

## config/initializers/active_model_intializer.rb

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.setup do |config|
  config.embed = :ids
  config.include = true
end
```

Second thing I tried

```
class RaceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id
  has_many :progresses , :serializer => ProgressSerializer
end

class ProgressSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_one :race , :serializer => RaceSerializer
end
```

Models

```
class Progress < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :race
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :progresses
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share your `Model.rb` files?

If **Progress** is main then **Races** underneath, this one should work.

```
class ProgressSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :races
  has_many :races
end

class RaceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
end
```

then try to delete has_many :progresses and add has_one :race to Race with attributes :id, :race

Comment: It works only from /races in this case. i want to get races when I call /progresses. the race_ids are [] empty for /progresses

Comment: So you mean to say that progresses has many races? Are you sure it's not a one-to-one where a race has one progress status?

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper, Actually its my bad to not asking him to share his `Model.rb` files.

Comment: @Rigel Just updated my Post Check that one and can you share your `Model.rb` files too.

Comment: Progress status is of individual athlete. A race has many progress each progress belongs to one participant. So If I access a particular race I should know what is individual participants status

Comment: Hi The solution was simple I am sorry to bother you but @7urkm3n I can proceed with the ans you provided and just add race_id simple thing that I missed. thanks for direction I dont need has_one

Comment: @Rigel, You could do this way too, I believe should work. in `RaceSerializer` add `attributes :id, :progresses` and `def progresses  object.progresses  end`